# htaccess rewrite username messing with pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can access profiles using **mysite.com/username** but I cannot access **mysite.com/home** which originally is **mysite.com/index.php?tab1=home**.

Same problem with all other pages, for example, I also cannot access **mysite.com/messages** which originally is **mysite.com/index.php?tab1=messages**

I want to access both profiles and pages using the same link. **mysite.com/profile** & **mysite.com/page**.

This is the htaccess code I used.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^\/\/]*)$  index.php?tab1=profile&id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\/\/]*)/([^\/\/]*)(|\/)$  index.php?tab1=profile&tab2=$2&id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\/\/]*)/([^\/\/]*)/([^\/\/]*)(|/)$  index.php?tab1=profile&tab2=$2&tab3=$3&id=$1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^\/\/]*)$  index.php?tab1=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/\/]*)$  index.php?tab1=profile&id=$1 [NC]
```

Which has the pattern `^([^\/\/]*)$`. So this matches "username", "home", **AND** "messages". That's why it's *always* going to the profile because that rule indiscriminately matches everything without a `/`.

Therefore, the last rule, which has the same pattern, **will never match anything**. You either need to make the profile a diffrent pattern, or hardcode the matches for "home" and "messages" and everything else that doesn't go to the profile.

So something like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(home|messages)$ index.php?tab1=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\/\/]*)$  index.php?tab1=profile&id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\/\/]*)/([^\/\/]*)(|\/)$  index.php?tab1=profile&tab2=$2&id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\/\/]*)/([^\/\/]*)/([^\/\/]*)(|/)$  index.php?tab1=profile&tab2=$2&tab3=$3&id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Or something like this maybe?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^profile-([^\/\/]*)$  index.php?tab1=profile&id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^profile-([^\/\/]*)/([^\/\/]*)(|\/)$  index.php?tab1=profile&tab2=$2&id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^profile-([^\/\/]*)/([^\/\/]*)/([^\/\/]*)(|/)$  index.php?tab1=profile&tab2=$2&tab3=$3&id=$1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\/\/]*)$  index.php?tab1=$1 [NC]
```

Making user profiles look like: `mysite.com/profile-username`